# Do simplicial join and product form a duoidal category structure?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

The join $\ast$ and the product $\times$ are both important monoidal structures on simplicial sets, but the way they interact is not so simple. For instance, neither distributes over the other. However, I believe there is a comparison map $(A\times B) \ast (C \times D) \to (A \ast C) \times (B \ast D)$, suggesting that they fit together into a [duoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/duoidal+category) structure on simplicial sets. Is this in fact the case? If so, has this duoidal category been studied before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably should have read more closely. If $C$ is any monoidal category which is also cartesian monoidal, then the combination of the two monoidal structures is duoidal. This is on the nlab page.

Comment: Perhaps more interestingly, it looks like the join actually distributes over the product (yes, not the other way around!) but only [colaxly](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colax-distributive+rig+category). But on reflection, I think this too is automatic for monoidal categories with finite products.